# installation of multiple setup.py in the same directory for local packages

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I'm working with the following directory structure:

```
package1/
    package_content1
package2/
    package_content2
setup.py
```

Up until now I usually installed with `pip install -e .` commenting the part of the `package1` to install `package2` of the `setup.py` and vice versa. Is there a way to create 2 different `setup.py` and declare the package I want to install without changing the whole structure of the project?

Something like `pip install -e 'package1'` or `pip install -e package1_setup.py`

---

UPDATE:

I have been testing other methods and I've come to the solution of installing it via `python3 package1_setup.py develop`. Although I see that it is not the preferred method, so if there is a way to do the same with `pip install -e` let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try having something like this

```
package1/
  package_content1
  setup.py
package2/
  package_content2
  setup.py
```

and you can do `pip install -e ./package1` or `pip install -e ./package2` from top level

Comment: oh now it works. I thought I couldn't do that because it didn't work out of the box. Turns out I also needed to change some variables inside the setup.py and  the `__init__.py`  inside `package_content`

Comment: For those who search a similar question to implement with openAI gym environments, it seems it does not work. As a solution, just create another directory where the setup.py and the whole env resides. It is a little cumbersome, but at least it works.